# How to redirect codeigniter controller controller function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have upload my localhost codeigniter project on live server.
but on live server i m getting redirection error like bellow.

```
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/genova/public_html/application/models/mymodel.php:2)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 675
```

is there any other method of redirection or how can i fix this?

Comment: Check that your Files and Class Names should have first letter upper case only

Comment: remove `?>` tag from the end of the model

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Thank You sir wolfgang1983.
with removal of ?> from model my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Into /mymodel.php you have a blank white space or some return carriage.

Remove any char before you php tag, also check if you have some echo functions... remember you have to avoid any kind of output into your model, that is the role of view.

I hope it could be useful my advice.

Comment: sir please tell me about to redirect with another method like javascript or guide me how to change cpanel header information to avoid this error